# Creating a Custom Component on React-Select

Tags: react-select

I am trying to create a custom component for React-Select, where I want to show more than just `label` in the select box. Kind of similar to Custom Placeholder, Option, Value, and Arrow Components part [here](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). The problem is that the link to the source code is not accessible anymore, and I found the documentation for styling pretty awful.

Assume I have my data like this:

```
[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'label': 'Alpha',
    'gender': 'Male'
    'country': 'USA'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'label': 'Beta',
    'gender': 'Male'
    'country': 'ENG'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'label': 'Charlie',
    'gender': 'Female'
    'country': 'GER'
  }
]
```

What I want to show in select box is something like:

> Alpha - Male - USA
>
> Beta - Male - ENG
>
> Charlie - Female - GER

But it should still filter only for labels, which are Alpha, Beta, and Charlie.

Right now I can only show Alpha, Beta, and Charlie. I am trying to understand how to do this from the documentation [here](http://www.react-select.com/styles) but for example there are no definitions for style keys and what they do. I could use some guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getOptionLabel` prop on your Select:

```
const label = (option) => `${option.label} - ${option.gender} - ${option.country}`;

<Select getOptionLabel={label} />
```

Comment: Hm, really usefull, I prefer to use components and then manipulate options, but it works too :) Best regards!